# Firebase with image url

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QunD.png) My data in firebase

```
ref = db.reference('/home1')
ref.set({
'slider':
[{"id" : "1" ,"name":"first","url":"images/gateaux/2D3A3227.jpg"}],
[{"id" : "2" ,"name":"second","url":"images/gateaux/pas/2D3A3470.jpg"}],
[{"id" : "3" ,"name":"third","url":"images/anniv/deux/2D3A3497.jpg"}],
[{"id" : "4" ,"name":"four","url":"images/anniv/2D3A3106.jpg"}],
[{"id" : "5" ,"name":"five","url":"images/anniv/2D3A3365.jpg"}],
[{"id" : "6" ,"name":"six","url":"images/gateaux/2D3A5245.jpg"}]
})


@app.route('/home1')
def home1():
ref = db.reference('/home1')
return str(ref.get())
```

And my code in React, i try to receive the data from firebase to my web

```
export default function Patiss() {
const [home1, sethome1] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
const usersRef = ref(database,'home1/slider')
get(usersRef).then((snapshot) => {
if(snapshot.exists()){
  const userArray = Object.entries(snapshot.val()).map(([id,data])=>({
     id,
    ...data,
  }));
  sethome1(userArray);
}else{
  console.log('no data available');
}
}).catch((error)=>{
console.error(error);
});
},[]);
const navigate = useNavigate()
const Keti = () =>{
navigate("/") 
}
return (
<div className=" mx-auto max-w-2xl px-4 py-2  ">
  <div className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-1">
  {home1.map((product, index) => { 
          return (
            <div key={index} className="productDisplay"
              onClick={() => {
                navigate(`/home1/${product.id}`);
              }}
            >
              <img
                src={product.url}
                alt={product.url}
                className="h-full w-full object-cover object-center lg:h-full lg:w-full"
              />
        </div>
    );
    })}
  </div>
</div>
)}
```

src={product.url} - i receive in localhost "images/gateaux/2D3A3227.jpg" and not the image of      url, how can get the image itself in my localhost?
I keep my image in realtime database.
Thanks for help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. There is no image in your database, just a partial path to a file (likely on your web server). Can you show the HTML that you generate, and the result you get in the browser?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Did I upload the image to  firebase correctly?
 I work with Tailwind
I added to the question a picture of how it is shown to me in localhost